# Old question with an accepted answer but not sourced

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions

Those questions are related to the same topic: memory handling with ASP Classic:

- [When exactly am I required to set objects to nothing in classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17991086/4375327)
- [VBScript Out Of Memory Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5092814/4375327)

I'm not questionning the truthiness of the answers (however they differ slightly), but the fact they aren't *sourced*. Moreover, those questions are quite old.

I'm looking for a sourced answer on this topic. I'm not sure here about the best approach: should I ask a new question, linking those ones and ask for reliable sources I haven't found? Won't be this likely a duplicate?

Comment: Put a bounty on one of them?

Comment: @oguzismail, indeed... Also [as said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399706/4375327) Cody Gray, it's possible to describe the goal of the bounty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What kind of "source" are you looking for? Which source would you consider to be reliable? Microsoft's documentation has never been particularly clear about this issue, which is why there's so much folklore. Worse, the technology is getting so long in the tooth that Microsoft's annoying tendency to rearrange or even remove content from MSDN is going to make it very difficult to locate an official source.

While I agree with [Oguz's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399705/old-question-with-an-accepted-answer-but-not-sourced#comment784469_399705) that you could [set a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to attract additional attention and hopefully an answer that meets your expectations, you will need to be extra clear in the bounty message to explain what exactly you're looking for.

You might also consider whether you would expect empirical proof in lieu of a source, as that might be easier to obtain. Especially with older languages/technologies that are no longer being updated, an experiment that verifies what the code generator emits, how the code behaves in the runtime environment, etc., can be just as useful and perhaps even more illustrative.

As an alternative to a bounty, depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I would also suggest that you go look at answers to equivalent questions for classic Visual Basic (e.g., VB 6). This was the same runtime environment, so the answers will be the same, but there was definitely more discussion on this in terms of classic VB than there was specifically for classic ASP. I know first-hand, because I remember personally researching this about a decade ago and reading most of the information that was out there. I don't remember a first-party source, but I do remember there being plenty of convincing evidence available.

Comment: "This was the same runtime environment." I wasn't sure about this, so I didn't add [another question dealing with this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/517006/4375327), which provides a [slightly different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/517202/4375327). The fact you can describe the goal of the bounty is interesting.

Comment: "Reliable" meant something more than a dogmatic "do that". I wrote a homemade API based on a [variation of IncludeOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552782/4375327) and got annoyed since it relies on a small set of global ActiveX objects. Thinking of a lot of HTTP requests leading to memory leaks... By the way you asnwered to my question. :)

Comment: @Amessihel Yeah, any time you start a bounty, you can select a canned summary reason, and then you also get a textbox where you can type in a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Got it thanks. The funny part here is that your answer, a meta one, is also more satisfactory on the technical question. :)

Comment: You happened to run into someone who knew a *lot* about classic VB back in the day, but now does other things and doesn't really answer technical questions about this stuff anymore. Basically, ignore most of the folklore surrounding this. It's rooted primarily in FUD, mostly uncertainty. The classic VB garbage collector is a simple reference-counting implementation, rooted in COM, like all of classic VB. There's almost no point in setting anything to `Nothing`; that's just cargo-cult programming. Locally-declared references get automatically set to `Nothing` at the end of a block, a la RAII.

Comment: (Added cargo-cult programming to my glossary.) Funnier, even a - quite old - [O'Reilly page](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ado-activex-data/1565924150/ch04s01.html) supports it.